# Recursion implementation

Tags: recursion

recursive method to find the number of different ways in which an integer k can be represented as sum , where each of the operands is a integer less than n...Please help me with the algorithm. I am not able to think of a recursive solution to this problem

Answer (score 1):

basically, my first idea would be the following:

```
int numberOfWays(int x)
{
    if(x <= 1)
        return 0;
    if(x == 2)
        return 1;
    // else:
    int res = 0;
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i <= x / 2; i++)
        res += numberOfWays(x - i);
    return res;
}
```

I'm going to give it a couple of tests and thoughts but that's about it.

Maybe a few words of explanation...

obviously, there is no way of writing 1 as the sum of integers < 1, and there is only one way of writing 2 as the sum of integers < 2: 2 = 1 + 1.

From there on, things get interesting. every integer x > 2 can be written as (x-1) + 1. since we are recursing, we now get the number of ways, (x-1) can be written as sum of integers < (x-1) and so on. eventually, we will reach (x-n) = 2, which will return 1.

from there on, we go back upwards, summing up the number of ways we found of representing the numbers, and voilá :)

Comment: Please correct me if i m wrong...shouldn't the function numberofWays have 2 input arguments k and n...

Comment: @user1640967 oh, I completely misread the question. :/ I thought of n and k as the same number. are there any constraints on k and n?